# Pushing Arduino GPS data to Firebase without WiFi Adapter?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

I am new to the Arduino world and as an introduction project I decided to take on a real time GPS tracking of an autonomous robot and I should be able to:

- Send GPS data from **Arduino Uno** board to Firebase
- Catch that data from Firebase (using React) and render it in a leafletjs map

What I have:

- Arduino Uno
- GPS Module: **GY-NEOMV2**

So far, I created a Firebase database and I am able to get dummy data I inserted manually back into React and render them into a lealfet map. But after many online searches, I found out that a permanent WiFi connection is necessary.

My question is: **Is there any way to send GPS data from my board to Firebase without my board being constantly connected to WiFi**? Mainly because the robot I am working on is supposed to be autonomous and I don't have a WiFi shield for that matter.

Would appreciate the help, **thanks** !

[image]

Comment: Hi CHRAIBI Mohammed Yassine, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/32168).

Comment: Yassine, do you mean you want to send GPS data only when WiFi is available? Or do you have another way of connecting to Firebase, maybe?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul quite the contrary, I was asking if I can send gps data without wifi?
I mean is there an alternative to WiFi in this case?

Comment: This question asks for software to do X using given hardware, so I would say it is on-topic. Reopening.

Comment: Firebase is a suite of 18 different products. I _guess_ you are talking about Firebase Cloud Messaging, if not please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that WiFi is not an option.

As you are building an autonomous robot, the Ethernet port is not usable either.

None of the other components you have seem to be able to communicate with the Internet, which is a precondition to accessing Firebase Cloud Messaging.

So I am afraid there is no software solution to your question.